# Doubt in limit of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Let $f(z)=e^{(-1/z^m)},$ where $m$ is positive integer then prove that limit of $f(z) $ does not exist at $z=0$ for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$?

My approach is for $m=1,2,3$ is, I take two sequences $a_n=1/n $ and $b_n=\iota/n$ such that both converges to $0$ but $f(a_n) $ and $f(b_n) $ goes to two different limit but i have confusion to prove for $m=4$? that is in this case what are two sequences ?? or some different approach?

My second doubt is for complex valued function $f(z)$ we find limit of $f(z)$ by writing real part and imaginary part of $f(z)$ and if limit of $f(z)$ exist iff limit of bith real and imaginary part exists but if i convert $f(z)$ in by putting $f(z)=u(r,\theta)+\iota v(r,\theta)$ then how to apply limit in $u(r,\theta), $ and $ v(r,\theta)$??

I hope I clearly explain my doubt
Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any $n$ there is a complex number $z_n$ such that $(z_n)^{m}=\frac 1 {2n\pi i}$ (Every complex number has  an $m-th$ root). There is also a complex num ber $\zeta_n$ such that $(\zeta_n)^{m}=\frac  1 {i\frac {\pi} 2+2n\pi i}$. Observe that $f(z_n)=1$ for each $n$, $f(\zeta_n)=-i$ for each $n$ and the sequences $(z_n), (\zeta_n)$ both tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.